# Using multiple arguments with apply

Tags: r, function, multiprocessing, apply

I am working with a potentially large data set and am struggling to apply a function to it.

Step 1: Let's create some data.

```
n<-3 #this number gets larger in application.
precision<-0.3 #This number gets smaller in application.
support<-matrix(seq(0,1,by=precision), ncol=1)
support_n<-as.matrix(combn(support, n))

foo<-function(x,y){
  part_1<-mean(x) # note x is a vector
  out<-part_1+y #note y is not a vector
  out
}
```

Step 2: I intend to make this multicore, since as n becomes large and precision becomes high, hell breaks loose. Therefore- if-then loops are not usable except for in small amounts, the bulk of the work must be done by apply, so I may use "mcapply" from the multicore package. I would like to use the foo function on the each combination of columnwise elements in object support_n

Step 3: The correct output- (I could not do this with apply)

```
out_final<-support_n #this will just be a placeholder for the right answers.
system.time(
  for(j in 1:dim(support_n)[2]){ #
    for(i in 1:n){
      out_final[i,j]<-foo(support_n[-i,j],support_n[i,j])
    }
  }
)
```

My question: How can I create out_final with apply in such a way as to be able to distribute the work in parallel with mcapply?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why do you want to replace a single matrix element with a vector (created by the `foo` function)?

Comment: What OS are you using?  Have you looked at `parallel` and other multicore packages?

Comment: Sven Hohenstein, I've clarified that I want to create out_final using apply commands instead of for(){} loops.  I vectorized foo because I it solved a problem in the past, it's irrelevant now.

CarlWitthoft I've looked at parallel and fiddled with it briefly. Currently the multicore package has mcapply and I anticipate that I will be using that. I am using linux ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64x. I'm curious why that's relevant.

Comment: Only matters because some of the multicore tools don't work under Windows.